# Django - ListView with form, How to redirect back to the Form page?

Tags: python, django, forms, listview

So, I have a ListView with exercices list (paginated 1 per page). In each page I have few input the user need to fill up. I managed to find a solution to how to attached the ListView with the Form but i cant find a solution on how to stay on the same page after the submit.

url's:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('programs/', ProgramListView.as_view(), name='web-programs'),
    path('programs/<int:pk>/', ExerciseListView.as_view(), name='program-detail'),
    path('data/', views.add_data, name='data-submit'),
```

views.py (updated with def form_valid):

```
class ExerciseListView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Exercise
    context_object_name = 'exercises'
    form_class = DataForm
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)

    def form_valid(self, dataform):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)
        for exe in exercises:
            dataform.instance.exercise = exe.pk
            return super(ExerciseListView, self).form_valid(dataform)


def add_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Data.objects.create(address=form.cleaned_data['form'])
            return redirect(?)
```

template.html:

```
{% extends "program/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> Program Exercises List </h3>
    {% for exercise in exercises %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    {% if user.is_superuser %}
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'exercise-update' exercise.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'exercise-delete' exercise.id %}">Delete</a>
                        <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.name }}</p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.name }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.description }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.breath_method}}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.recovery_method }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.measure_method }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.load_share }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.notes }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.extra_info }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.reps }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.sets }}</p>
                </div>
                  <form action="{% url 'data-submit' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Exercise Measurements</legend>
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if is_paginated %}

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous Exercise</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Exercise</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% url 'web-home' %}">Exit</a>
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py:

```
class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['exercise', 'set_number', 'spo2', 'hr']
```

In the views.py, i left the "redirect" with "?" because i don't know what to add there.
I can't change the "action" in the template.html because this link is for `def add_data(request)`
so it will save my inputs.
Once i submit, it saves the new data to my DB but i don't know how to stay on the same page for continue my exercises.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Program in Exercise so use it get program id looking at your DataForm you have exercise field if am not wrong is foreign-key

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
def add_data(request):
    page=request.GET.get('page')
    page='?page={}'.format(page) if page else ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('program-detail', kwargs={'pk':data.exercise.program.pk})+ page)
```

For redirecting to same page you check and pass page parmameter in url  in form action like

```
<form action="{% url 'data-submit' %}{%if request.GET.page%}?page={{request.GET.page}}{%endif%}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: Yes, You are right, I do have it as a foreign-key.  I tried it now, It seems like he doesn't recognize it - "'program-detail', pk=data.exercise.program.pk". I have a red line underneath data. Any idea why?

Comment: I think that redirect method can not receive pk as a parameter. I couldn't find it in the documentations, but i might be wrong.

Comment: here is documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

Comment: you may also user full url redirect('/programs/{}/'.format(data.exercise.program.id))

Comment: I tried both ways, it doesn't recognize the "pk=data....". Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: did you put data=form.save() and return redirect under same indent if yes print data.exercise.program.pk check if its printing pk

Comment: I double checked it, now its working perfect. Any idea how to add the current paginate  page so it will redirect me to the right page every submit and not to the first one? Thanks.

Comment: sure you just need add page in post url and pass in redirect ill update answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tired it, It seems like it try to look in the wrong address though, ""POST /data/%20?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 404 4762" insted of "POST /programs/%20?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 404 4762. It takes the URL for the add_data function. Any idea? In the action url it's not suppose to take the page number, just to call the function that handle the form

Comment: OK, I think i made it works well now. I needed to change the URL for 'data-submit'. I changed it to - programs/data. Now it redirect me to the same page. Thanks.

Comment: hi if you are good with the answer i provided close the question.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to assign the form.instance.exercise to be added automatically without any input from the user. I tried to use the def form_valid but for now, I wasn't able to make it work. Is there a way it can be done? I will edit my views.py with my updated code for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use jQuery to achieve this result. Download it, paste to js folder and add it to `program/base.html`

```html
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
```

2. I'd like to recommend you to add a js block into `base.html`
   somewhere at the bottom of the file

```
{% block js %}{% endblock js %}
```

3. Then, do this:

```html
<block js>
<script>
$("#submit-btn").submit(function(event) {
  // prevent default action, so no page refreshing
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var posting = $.post( form.attr('action'), form.serialize() );

  posting.done(function(data) {
    // done
  });
  posting.fail(function(data) {
    // fail
  });
});
</script>
<endblock>

...

<form action="{% url 'data-submit' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
<legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Exercise Measurements</legend>
  {{ form|crispy }}
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="submit-btn" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Kind of got lost with this solution. How this will help me redirect back? Sorry for my misunderstanding, I am not using that long with this framework.

Comment: It sends post request without opening new view/url, so you’re staying at the same page. It’s called ajax.

Comment: Ok, make sense as a good solution. What do I add in the "redirect" in my function?

Comment: Nothing. Use `return HttpResponse(status=200)` instead. Or any another code if form is not valid etc..

Comment: Do i need to create program/base.html? where exactly to locate it? in my templates? Do i need to call it? Thanks.

Comment: @ShaiShmuel look at the first line in `template.html`. `{% extends "program/base.html" %}`. Don't you know where it is located? It's your file, I didn't create any new file, just extended what you have.

Comment: You right, I didn't understand you at first, Sorry!